# Implementation of the authorization system, in which each individual specific permission gives access to a specific column in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, permissions

I am creating API, in which I let users read some data from the database, but I want to deny access to some columns in my table.

For example, there is permission `users.show.name_of_example_column`, which should access to the column `name_of_example_column` in `users` table.

Spatie/Laravel-Permission is responsible for associating users with permissions and roles in my API.

Users in my system have 2 permissions:

- `users.show.id`
- `users.show.name`

Administrators have all permissions.

I already made an example to show you what result I want (depending on which role I have).

```php
public function index($perPage = 30)
{
   $user = Auth::User();
   $fields = [];
   if($user->hasPermissionTo('users.show.id')) {
       $fields[] = 'id';
   }
   if($user->hasPermissionTo('users.show.name')) {
       $fields[] = 'name';
   }
   if($user->hasPermissionTo('users.show.email')) {
       $fields[] = 'email';
   }
   return User::Select($fields)->paginate($perPage);
}
```

Of course, this example is bad practice. Should I do it in User model via accessors or maybe somewhere else? What is the correct way? Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I tried to check permission in accessors

Here is example

```php
public function getEmailAttribute($value)
{
   if(Auth::User()->hasPermissionTo('users.show.email')) {
     return $value;
   }
   return false;
}
```

but when it returns `false` it doesn't unset (remove) the 'email' attribute from the collection. It just replaces original value with 'false'.

Comment: Using accessors/mutators looks like a better option.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I need.

Comment: Please, look at my update. I have one issue with accessors.

Comment: Sorry for replying late, check the post below to see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Accessors cannot be used to for hiding model attributes, what you rather need to is to mark those select attributes as hidden 
l

So add a generic method in your model that will do this hiding for you based on the permission levels

```
public function marker()
{

    // loop over the attributes 

    // check permission for $attr - email

    if($hasPermissionForEmail)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        $this->makeHidden('email');
    }

}
```

Now

```
$a->marker();
```

Note : it may not seem to work when you directly access an attribute like $a->email but when the object get sent in a response either as json or an array it would work